# jQuery UI combobox Ajax options

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I need to customize the combobox widget build from the jQuery UI Autocomplete
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Currently drop down options are predefined from the SELECT tag OPTIONS or from a JSON array.

```
//getter
var source = $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "source" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "source", ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"] );
```

I want to populate the combobox options from a Ajax URL, how can i customize the widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a demo on [how to do this via AJAX](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp), you should just make sure your array is JSON encoded before it is returned to the autocomplete component.

If you're using PHP, take a look at the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

Does this answer your question?